# find_elements returns empty string using XPATH contains text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

i am using xpath with contains text in order to find all occurrences of a specific value on dynamic checkbox and it returns elements with empty string

CODE

```
for value in values:
    self.action_chains().move_to_element(search_field).perform()
    xpath = f"//*[contains(@class, 'selectList')]//{tag}[contains(text(),'{value}')]" wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
    search_field.send_keys(value)
    elements_list = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
    for element in elements_list:
       if element.text == '':
         print("empty value") 
           if element.text.strip() == value:                                                                 
               self.action_chains().move_to_element(element).perform()
                            element.click()


@allure.step
def get_search_field(self):
    search_inputs = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@placeholder='Search...']")
    for search_input in search_inputs:
        if search_input.is_displayed():
            return search_input
```

with value = '120+' and tag='span' .
This returned me two elements with empty string.
I do not get why those are empty
Any idea ?
Thank you in advance

HTML

```
<div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="checkboxLayer show">
   <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="helperContainer">
      <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="line"><button data-v-c3fbf650="" type="button" class="multiselect-select-all v-btn v-btn--is-elevated v-btn--has-bg theme--light v-size--small primary"><span class="v-btn__content"> Select all </span></button></div>
      <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="line" style="position: relative;"><input data-v-c3fbf650="" placeholder="Search..." type="text" class="inputFilter"><button data-v-c3fbf650="" type="button" class="multi-select-clear"><i data-v-c3fbf650="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate multi-select-clear-icon material-icons theme--light material-symbols-outlined" size="18" style="font-size: 18px; font-variation-settings: &quot;FILL&quot; 0, &quot;wght&quot; 300, &quot;GRAD&quot; 200, &quot;opsz&quot; 48;">clear</i></button></div>
   </div>
   <div data-v-c3fbf650="" class="checkBoxContainer">
      <ul data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectList">
         <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
            <!----><span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5">  </span>
         </li>
         <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
            <!----><span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5"> 0 </span>
         </li>
         <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
            <!----><span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5"> 01-29 </span>
         </li>
         <li data-v-c3fbf650="" class="selectItem">
            <!----><span data-v-c3fbf650="" class="ml-5"> 120+ </span>
         </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Add the code you are using to determine those elements contain empty string. Also, presence just means that the elements just exist in the DOM, not that they are visible or clickable. If you are going to pull text from them use visible, if you are going to click them use clickable. In this case you should use `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located()`... that might fix the empty string issue.

Comment: Another issue is that you are getting 2 elements when your HTML only includes one. That could be another problem... your locator is not specific enough to only get the element you are looking for.

Comment: An efficiency... `wait.until()` returns the waited for element(s) so you can assign the return to your variable, e.g. `elements_list = wait.until()`, simplifying your code.

Comment: thank you for your response . but visibility doesn't work when i have a long list of options ..
i don't understand why i am getting two elements , and why the xpath returns element.text =''

Comment: Another issue is that you are getting 2 elements when your HTML only includes one. That could be another problem... 
but why ? my value = '120+' , why i have element.text = ''
and it works randomly

Comment: You need to find out why two elements are being returned. That tells me that there are two elements on the page that match your locator which means your locator isn't specific enough.

Comment: A link to the page would give us the answer